# how do you link css to a jade file?

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I am currently trying to link `normalize.css` but its not working (using socket an express)

```
html
        head
                title= "Real time web chat"
                link(href='/css/normalize.css')
                script(src='/chat.js')
                script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
                script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js')
        body
                #content(style='width: 100%; height: 600px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; border: solid 1px #999; overflow-y: scroll;')
                .controls
                        | Name: 
                        input#name(style='width:350px;')

                        input#field(style='width:350px; display: inline; margin-left -90px;')
                        input#send(type='button', value='send')
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need `rel`

```
link(href='/css/normalize.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Comment: when I view source it says "Cannot GET /css/normalize.css"

Comment: You probably get wrong path then. If you use express default folder template, `normalize.css` should be in `public/css/'.

Comment: Thanks I had it in a CSS folder I had created myself

Comment: The `rel=stylesheet` was the solution for me. Thanks